# A ROS subscriber like node in behavior tree(cpp) that can continuously updating data to blackboard

Tags: ros, behavior-tree

I want to have a node that has a ROS subscriber in it so that it can update blackboard data asynchronously, is it possible to do so? if so, how to place this kind of node; if not, does it have some conflicts with the behavior tree logic?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that clear.

However it is possible to create ROS node that publish data on topics or read data from topics. So it should be possible to create a node that publish some data on a topic and use this topic to update "blackboard data".

Comment: Yeah, "use this topic" means that there's a subscriber node in the behavior tree, where should I put this node in behavior tree so it can update data asynchronously?

Comment: Could you add a schema of your current behavior tree to your post ?

Comment: Please don't use an answer to ask questions.  That's what the comments are for.

Comment: Sadly I do not have enough reputation and I wanted to help...